# Finding the largest sequence of identical digits using recursive function (c++)

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to find the largest sequence of identical digits in a given integer using a recursive function.
For example:

```
input: "2221", output: 3
input: "2223333", output: 4
input: "222333", output: 3
```

For some reason the code sometimes works correctly and sometimes it doesn't. when I input "1112" then it gives me the correct output (3), but when I input "1111555", I expected to get the output 4, but instead got 6.
Also, I can't change the parameters that the function receives so if someone knows how can I insert the parameters inside the function instead of outside (if I insert them inside the function then the output I receive is always 0)
I'd really appreciate the help so thank you in advance :)

My code:

```
int currentLength = 0, maxLength = 0;
int currentDigit = -1;
int maxSequence(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0)
        return maxLength;
    int digit = num % 10;
    if (digit == currentDigit) {
        maxLength= 1 + maxSequence(num / 10);
    }
    else {
        currentDigit = digit;
        if (maxLength > 1)
        {
            maxLength = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            maxLength = 1;
        }
        return maxSequence(num / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger to see why it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: Try doing it without global variables. Mixing recursion with external state leads to very confusing logic.

Comment: Use a helper function to keep track of state.

Comment: why using recursion? Even if you do need recursion to meet requirements of an exercise, you can start with a solution taht does not use recursion. It would be much simpler. Also converting the number to a `std::string` is much simpler. Start with the simple and then only add complexity in tiny steps until you meet the requirements. This is a much simpler strategy than starting from the most complex which doesnt work. For me your code is too complicated. I cannot understand what it does

Comment: tenfour do you know how can I do that? because as I've stated before, one I insert the global variables into the function then it doesn't work correctly anymore and will only output 0

Comment: Also please turn on compiler warnings ... the posted function sometimes completes without returning anything that is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Danielle "it doesn't work correctly" In that you have a function referring to names that are undefined? yes, you will need to pass those as parameters to your recursive function. You would have `int maxSequence(int num, int currentLength = 0, int maxLength = 0, int currentDigit = -1)`, and the recursive calls would include them

Comment: @Caleth The problem is I can't change the parameters that the function receives, and I can add additional functions only if those functions are also recursive so I'm totally lost on that one..

Answer (score 1):

Recursion and mutable global variables is a nasty combination.
You can add the parameters to a different function and call that instead.

Something like this:

```
// Since you can't use std::max.
int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

int maxSequenceHelper(int number, int last, int length, int maximum)
{
    int digit = number % 10;
    if (digit == last)
    {
        length += 1;
        maximum = max(length, maximum);
    }
    else
    {
        length = 1;
    }
    return number < 10
        ? maximum
        : maxSequenceHelper(number / 10, digit, length, maximum);
}

int maxSequence(int number)
{
    return maxSequenceHelper(number / 10, number % 10, 1, 1);
}
```

---

And here is a version without any assignments, making it slightly easier to reason about:

```
int maxSequenceHelper(int number, int last, int length, int maximum)
{
    const int digit = number % 10;
    const int new_length = digit == last ? length + 1 : 1;
    const int new_maximum = max(new_length, maximum);
    return number < 10
        ? new_maximum
        : maxSequenceHelper(number / 10, digit, new_length, new_maximum);
}
```

Comment: I can add additional functions that'll help to my function but the problem is that they're also supposed to be recursive. Can you help me convert your other function to a recursive one? or is there an easier solution without adding another function?

Comment: @Danielle the 4 arg `maxSequence` *is* recursive

Comment: @Caleth I'm really new to c++ so I'm not sure about some parts.. what do "?" and ":" represnt? also where did max came from (max as in max(length, maximum))?

Comment: @Danielle Perhaps the recursion becomes clearer with a little renaming.

Comment: @Danielle `?:` is the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) is from <algorithm>

Comment: `condition ? truthy : falsey` is a conditional expression; its value is `truthy` if `condition` is true, `falsey` otherwise.

Comment: Oh I see. first of all, thank you for the help so far :) Secondly, I didn't learn how to use the algorithm library yet so I'm not allowed to use it.. is there any other way to overcome it?

Comment: Yes, it's a function that returns the largest of it's arguments. you can write that yourself

Comment: @Danielle I added a `max` as well.